# Why is my dust collector way too loud?

Tags: dust-collection, noise

I have a 3/4 HP dust collector which uses an induction motor. I bought it on the assumption that the fact that it uses an induction motor means that it shouldn't be too loud, but it sounds like a jet engine. I suspect that the sound is not generated by the motor but rather by the fan. Is there something that can be done to lower the sound coming from the fan?

The dust extractor I have is similar to the one in the photo below, but the dust filter is fabric. The layout of the parts is identical, the motor is on top with nothing covering it, the filter and dust bag's location is the same.

[image: example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are moderately noisy beasts. The best that can be said for them is that they're less noisy than a shop vacuum, and much less noisy than any of the large tools you're likely to connect to them. More expensive units, with thicker metal components, may be a bit quieter.

You can try to reduce resonance in the frame, but anything you try to do to the blower's internals will impede function. Some folks build what amounts to a sound-deadening closet to isolate dust collectors; that's your only hope for anything resembling whisper-quiet operation.

The other approach is to turn them on only when needed -- ie, when you'll be wearing hearing protection anyway. Remote controls exist to make that easier, either pushbutton or sensing the current of the cutting tool when it's turned on. The fanciest version, for those who are setting up larger workshops, automatically opens the blast gate(s) for just those tool(s) as well, so the whole dust collection system automagically configures itself as and when needed. (My shop's small enough that I doubt I'll be able to justify permanent ducting.)

Comment: I connect the collector directly to the machine and it has an automatic start option so its on only when the saw/planer are on. Its a good thing that I am a big fan of hand tools :)

Answer (score 3):

That roar is really part of the nature of the beast. Some folks tuck their DCs into sound-insulated closets for that very reason, some set up the DC outdoors or in another room.

Answer (score 1):

They are loud. Just the way it is. If you try to modify it for sound you reduce the efficacy. The best way is to put it in another room. The closet thing works to. Exhausting it outside helps a little as well.